# Replacing values in a data.table according to multiple columns names

Tags: r, data.table

I posted this question [about replacing data in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184274/replacing-values-in-a-column-that-match-multiple-columns-of-another-data-frame-i), and tried to use the solution proposed by tyluRp to my data, but then I got another problem.

My example data,

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    c(rep("AFG", 3), rep("AUS", 3)),
    rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2),
    rep(0, 6), 
    rep(0, 6), 
    othr = c(10:15),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

colnames(df1) <- c("Country", "Category", "2000", "2001", "Oth")

df2 <- data.frame(
    rep("AFG", 2),
    c("a", "b"), 
    c(7, 8),
    c(1, 2),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)
colnames(df2) <- c("Country", "Category", "2000", "2001")
```

The solution proposed works for year 2000, and certain values in `df1` are replaced by `df2`:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- setDT(df1)
dt2 <- setDT(df2)
desirable_output <- dt1[dt2, on = c("Country", "Category"), as.character(2000) := i.2000]
```

But I can't manage to get the calculation for both years,
my attempt:

```
years <- c(2000:2001)

for(i in years){
    desirable_output <- dt1[dt2, on = c("Country", "Category"), as.character(i) := paste("i.", years, sep="")]
}
```

How could I solve this situation? What I'm missing about`:=`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use get : `get(paste("i.", years, sep=""))` should work

Comment: The `colnames` in `df1` aren't complete I think.

Comment: Thanks @denis  but `get(paste("i.", years, sep=""))` replaces with `dt2$2000` in both columns (so correctly in `dt1$2000`, but wrongly in `dt1$2001`)

Comment: `dt1[dt2, (as.character(years)) := lapply(years, function(x) get(paste0("i.", x))), on=c("Country", "Category")]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do for a limited, and small, number of columns

```
    dt1[dt2, on = c("Country", "Category"), `:=` (`2000` = i.2000, `2001` = i.2001)][]
```